# Has "Republish Only" Changed In Tridion 2013?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1

My previous process for restoring a production CMS content to a development environment was once the DB had been restored & publishing/content re-configured, I would start by republishing all dynamic component templates (leaving the "Republish Only" checked). This would republish all of the components (and their DCPs) that were marked "published" in the production environment.

When I did this in 2009 & 2011, it worked like a charm. Only the components that were intentionally published in the production environment would be published in the development one. With 2013 SP1, however, this seems to have changed.

If I select a Dynamic Component Template, choose to *publish it with republish only* and look at the items to publish, **I see listed components that are not published** to either Stage or Live (and never have been) - if I then select Publish, those items are indeed part of the publish transaction. Since I'm in the midst of upgrading from 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1, I can perform this exact same test on the older environment (exact same data) and those items do not show in the items to publish dialog.

In the 2013 environment, it's not like it's republishing ALL of the unpublished components that match the schemas linked in the dynamic component template - it's still just a handful. The particular component I tracked down was being used in a component list which itself was used on a PAGE that was published... That was the only "published" connection I could find for the component.

Was this an intentional change on the part of SDL? Am I missing some new checkbox that tells it to behave like it used to? Am I looking at a bug here (none of the Hotfixes out there seem to address this)?

Comment: There are some differences noted (within this forum) on the difference in resolving between previous versions and 2013 SP1. I can confirm this behaviour in 2013 SP1. To me this looks like something worth reporting to SDL if you can through your client.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket with SDL and they've confirmed this behavior. They said it only seems to occur with CTs and not PTs, SGs or Publications. Sounds like they're digging into why it is happening (and I'm hoping this might lead to a HotFix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug (specific to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 using MSSQL) and SDL has created a HotFix for it - Hotfix TT88250. SDL was pretty rapid in getting this Hotfix done for me, which I greatly appreciated.

I haven't fully tested this yet, so if I have issues with it, I'll report back.

Here's the information from the Hotfix readme:

```
"Problem description:
Resolver for 'Republish Only' on a Dynamic component template includes items that were not published to the chosen target.
MS SQL Server specific.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a publication where you have a dynamic component template published (as part of some CP with a component) to a particular target.
2. Create a new component1 from a schema associated to this CT. Save it but do not publish.
3. Create a new component2 from a schema associated to this CT and publish it to a different target. 
4. Publish the CT from the publication and leave 'Republish only' checked. See the items to publish and it will include new items and items published to other targets.

Hotfix description:
Logic in stored procedure to determine if specific component was published to specified publication target with specified component template was incorrect."
```

Note: This Hotfix is dependent on an earlier Hotfix as well - TT87401

Comment: Thought I'd report back that the Hotfix seems to be working well. My published packages for certain dynamic component templates/presentations were halved in size now that it was only including the correct published components.

Comment: I'm having an additional problem with dynamic component presentations that may either be related to this hotfix or is an issue with 2013 SP1.

The problem is when I publish a component (with the intent to publish its associated dynamic component presentations) the DCPs are not published (not in the package). If I publish the dynamic component template itself though, then it does update the DCPs correctly.

I've submitted another request with SDL and I'll report back as to whether it's related to the previous issue or not.

Comment: Figured I should tie out my comment above. Apparently the problem I was seeing was not related to the hotfix, but something that changed in the kernel of Tridion 2013. Unfortunately, even though SDL acknowledged there was a change that was causing the broken behavior I was seeing (I sent some detailed log comparisons between 2011 & 2013), they couldn't do a HotFix for it. Instead I'm having to implement a Custom Resolver to replace what I was able to do with a simple C# TBB previously.